# useReducer - Enforce only one true value without explicitly setting others false?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, use-reducer

I'm looking for a smarter way to enforce
one value true, setting the others to false

[This Python q&a suggests an enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57792789/only-one-boolean-value-allowed-true-at-the-time)
(I'm not familiar with either)

I can already

```
switch (action.type) {
        case 'loadCurrent':
         return {...state, 
loadCurrent: true, 
loadPrev: false, etc ...};
```

---

But this is a lot of boilerplate and intuition (as well as that linked python question) tell me there's a more elegant solution.

```
function reducer (state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'loadCurrent':
      return {...state, loadCurrent: true};
    case 'fetchNew':
      return {...state, fetchNew: true};
    case 'loadPrevHook':
      return {...state, loadPrevHook: true };
    case 'loadNextHook':
      return {...state, loadNextHook: true };
    case 'loaded':
      return {...state, loaded: true };
  }
}


 const initialState = { 
loadCurrent: false,
fetchNew: false, 
loadPrevHook: false, 
loadNextHook: false, 
loaded: true }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention another even greater motivation besides syntax/boilerplate… having mutually exclusive load states, so that a bug isn’t accidentally introduced which perhaps fetches and renders two different items at a time…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having separate properties for these doesn't make the most sense. Put all the data into a single property instead - perhaps call it `loadStage` or whatever you think is appropriate.

If, as the code here suggests, the state doesn't have any other properties, just setting the `action.type` looks like it'd do.

```
function reducer (state, action) {
  return { loadStage: action.type };
}
```

If you expanded the reducer to include other actions as well not related to the loading actions, you could make an array corresponding to the loading actions.

```
const loadStageActions = ['loadCurrent', 'fetchNew', 'loadPrevHook', 'loadNextHook', 'loaded'];
function reducer (state, action) {
  if (loadStageActions.includes(action.type)) {
    return { ...state, loadStage: action.type };
  }
  // implement other logic here
}
```

Then, in the rest of your code, just check the one string property instead of the multiple booleans. Eg instead of doing `state.loadCurrent`, do `state.loadStage === 'loadCurrent'`.